# NetworkManager hotspot Customisation

Tags: network-manager

I'm trying to customize a hotspot created by NetworkManager. But I still have some problems.

I've found how to configure the dhcp adresses provide to client : 
In : /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/famous
Part : [ipv4]
Add following line :

address1=192.168.125.1/24,192.168.125.1

The result of this can be seen by the following command :
ps -edf |grep dns
nobody    2581  2394  0 15:05 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file --no-hosts --keep-in-foreground --bind-interfaces --except-interface=lo --clear-on-reload --strict-order --listen-address=192.168.125.1 --dhcp-range=192.168.125.10,192.168.125.254,60m --dhcp-option=option:router,192.168.125.1 --dhcp-lease-max=50 --pid-file=/var/run/nm-dnsmasq-wlp3s0b1.pid --conf-dir=/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq-shared.d

Now, I want to change the dhcp-lease-max parameter.

I've try by creating the /etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq-shared.d/dnsmasq.conf but without succes.

Has somebody an idea ?

thx,